# Favicon not showing on my website

Tags: html, favicon

For some reason my favicon doesn't show up on my website. I tested mydomain.com/favicon.ico and I can see the icon.I'm using latest version of safari.
I'm using the code below in my head tags. What's the issue? Tks

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Comment: For me it works. What browsers have you tried?

Comment: Works also for me! If you mean it does not work in sub directories, try: `<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />`

Comment: Ok thanks. Just tested it with firefox and it works but doesn't work with latest version of safari...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:
   `<link rel="icon"
      type="image/
png"
      href="http://
example.com/
myicon.png">`

Answer (score 3):

You are most likely using Internet Explorer to test the page. IE doesn't support anything but the ICO format, and your favicon is a png.

Use http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/ or similar to convert the file to ICO.